# Fast Fourier Transform for non log 2

Tags: java, signal-processing, fft

I want to implement Fast Fourier Transform in Java for chord recognition, but I don't really get it. It says that the number of samples should be a power of 2, so what should we do for a song that doesn't have number of samples equal to a power of 2? Also I would like to know about the STFT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You normally generate an [STFT](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-time_Fourier_transform) over a sliding window throughout your file. The size of the window is chosen to give a reasonable time period over which the characteristics of the sound do not change greatly. Typically a window might be around 10 ms, so if your sample rate is 44.1kHz for example, then you might use a window size N = 512, so that you get the required duration and a power of 2 in size. You then take successive chunks of size N samples through the file, and generate the FFT for each N point chunk. (Note: in most cases you actually want the *magnitude* of the FFT output, in order to get an estimate of the power spectrum.) For increased resolution the chunks can overlap, e.g. by 50%, but this increases the processing load of course. The end result is a succession of short term spectra, so in effect you have a 3D matrix (amplitude v frequency v time) which describes the contents of the sound in the frequency domain.

Answer (score 2):

Normally what you do is just pad the data with zeros to make it a power of two.